# Can't remove aws-sdk from NodeJS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, package.json

I'm working on decreasing the size of one of our Lambda functions, currently configured for Node 12.x.

I've moved the aws-sdk dependency from "dependencies" to "devDependencies", but it's still included even though I use "npm install --production", or "npm prune --production".

We have only direct dependency that have listed aws-sdk, and that is listed as a peer dependency, "@acuris/aws-es-connection". If I remove that one from package.json for testing purposes, aws-sdk is removed as expected.

Not sure what I'm missing here?

Comment: May I ask why are you trying to decrease your lambda size at the first place?

Comment: Due to other dependencies we're closing in on 250 MB unzipped, and the aws-sdk is ~65 MB of them.

Comment: As I guessed! the best option would be to create a docker image of your lambda on ECR and create the lambda function with that image, you wouldn't be having problems with size then!